# How to correctly represent 3D rotation in games

Tags: opengl, math, 3d, rotation, quaternions

In most 3D platform games, only rotation around the Y axis is needed since the player is always positioned upright.

However, for a 3D space game where the player needs to be rotated on all axises, what is the best way to represent the rotation?

I first tried using Euler angles:

```
glRotatef(anglex, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(angley, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(anglez, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

The problem I had with this approach is that after each rotation, the axises change. For example, when anglex and angley are 0, anglez rotates the ship around its wings, however if anglex or angley are non zero, this is no longer true. I want anglez to always rotate around the wings, irrelevant of anglex and angley.

I read that quaternions can be used to exhibit this desired behavior however was unable to achieve it in practice.

I assume my issue is due to the fact that I am basically still using Euler angles, but am converting the rotation to its quaternion representation before usage.

```
struct quaternion q = eulerToQuaternion(anglex, angley, anglez);
struct matrix m = quaternionToMatrix(q);
glMultMatrix(&m);
```

However, if storing each X, Y, and Z angle directly is incorrect, how do I say "Rotate the ship around the wings (or any consistent axis) by 1 degree" when my rotation is stored as a quaternion?

Additionally, I want to be able to translate the model at the angle that it is rotated by. Say I have just a quaternion with q.x, q.y, q.z, and q.w, how can I move it?

Comment: This is too fuzzy. I probably know what you want, but don't know how to start...

Comment: I have a working quaternion library implemented into my game, but am unsure of how exactly to rotate around a consistent axis. For example, always around the wings irrelevant of the rotation on the other axises.

Comment: So, the "state" of any object of your game in space is described by a vector (displacement from origin) and a quaternion (orientation around its center)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quaternions are very good way to represent rotations, because they are efficient, but I prefer to represent the full state "position and orientation" by 4x4 matrices.

So, imagine you have a 4x4 matrix for every object in the scene. Initially, when the object is unrotated and untraslated, this matrix is the identity matrix, this is what I will call "original state". Suppose, for instance, the nose of your ship points towards -z in its original state, so a rotation matrix that spin the ship along the z axis is:

```
Matrix4 around_z(radian angle) {
    c = cos(angle);
    s = sin(angle);
    return Matrix4(c, -s, 0, 0,
            s, c, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

now, if your ship is anywhere in space and rotated to any direction, and lets call this state `t`, if you want to spin the ship around z axis for an `angle` amount as if it was on its "original state", it would be:

```
t = t * around_z(angle);
```

And when drawing with OpenGL, `t` is what you multiply for every vertex of that ship. This assumes you are using column vectors (as OpenGL does), and be aware that matrices in OpenGL are stored columns first.

Basically, your problem seems to be with the order you are applying your rotations. See, quaternions and matrices multiplication are non-commutative. So, if instead, you write:

```
t = around_z(angle) * t;
```

You will have the `around_z` rotation applied not to the "original state" z, but to global coordinate z, with the ship already affected by the initial transformation (roatated *and* translated). This is the same thing when you call the `glRotate` and `glTranslate` functions. The order they are called matters.

Being a little more specific for your problem: you have the absolute translation `trans`, and the rotation around its center `rot`. You would update each object in your scene with something like:

```
void update(quaternion delta_rot, vector delta_trans) {
    rot = rot * delta_rot;
    trans = trans + rot.apply(delta_trans);
}
```

Where `delta_rot` and `delta_trans` are both expressed in coordinates relative to the original state, so, if you want to propel your ship forward 0.5 units, your `delta_trans` would be (0, 0, -0.5). To draw, it would be something like:

```
void draw() {
    // Apply the absolute translation first
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatevf(&trans);

    // Apply the absolute rotation last
    struct matrix m = quaternionToMatrix(q);
    glMultMatrix(&m);

    // This sequence is equivalent to:
    // final_vertex_position = translation_matrix * rotation_matrix * vertex;

    // ... draw stuff
}
```

The order of the calls I choose by reading the manual for `glTranslate` and `glMultMatrix`, to guarantee the order the transformations are applied.

**About `rot.apply()`**

As explained at Wikipedia article [Quaternions and spatial rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation), to apply a rotation described by quaternion `q` on a vector `p`, it would be `rp = q * p * q^(-1)`, where `rp` is the newly rotated vector. If you have a working quaternion library implemented on your game, you should either already have this operation implemented, or should implement it now, because this is the core of using quaternions as rotations.

For instance, if you have a quaternion that describes a rotation of 90° around (0,0,1), if you apply it to (1,0,0), you will have the vector (0,1,0), i.e. you have the original vector rotated by the quaternion. This is equivalent to converting your quaternion to matrix, and doing a matrix to colum-vector multiplication (by matrix multiplication rules, it yields another column-vector, the rotated vector).

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. Could you go into more depth as to what would be in the "rot.apply" function?